# How to read a text file from my application's bundle and display it in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to read a text file  called "config.txt" from my application's bundle and display it in a UITextView. The code below is not working, can anyone help me?

IF i want to display it on a View then what i should do as well.

I have a IBOutlet to a UITextView, also please tell me how to change the text font and colour programmatically.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"txt"];  
if (filePath) {  
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (myText) {  
        textView.text= myText;    
    }
}


[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: what happens when you do a NSLog on myText ?

Comment: @tegbains When i do NSlog on myText i am getting all the data content in config.txt but i am not able to display on textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure `textView` is not `nil` and that you setup the IBOutlet connection in Interface Builder.

To set the font and color of the UITextView programmatically, use:

```
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f];
```

and

```
textView.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

See:

- [iOS Developer Library - UIFont Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [iOS Developer Library - UITextView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)

Comment: i have checked but the above code is not working, the file content in config.txt is not gettting displayed

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `if (myText) {`, does myText contain the text from inside config.txt at that point in time?

Comment: The only conclusion I can see from the code you posted is that that your `textView` is not pointing to the UITextView you are seeing on the screen, or the text color is white.  What happens if you do `textView.text = @"Test";`, does it display that inside the text view?

Answer (score 0):

Is your file extension ".text" or ".txt"?

Also, why are you reading the file into an NSData object and then an NSString?

Comment: its .txt
sorry i am new to Iphone development so  iam confused...i was going through tutorial and got it.can u plz suggest me with sample code what correction should be done

Answer (score 0):

see whether your config.txt is normal or  messy code
I mean you may check your txt file in the X-code surroundings

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"txt"]; 

if (filePath) {  
    NSError *error;
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(!error) {
        if (myText) {  //config file contains text
            textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@“Times New Roman” size:16.0f];
            textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textView.text= myText;    
        }
    }
    else {
        //Handle error while reading file
    }
}
else {
    //File path does not exists. Handle error
}
```